# Inner product involving operators

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I was wondering about inner product spaces and adjoints. The more I think about this the more I seem to be confusing myself.

I am not sure if given T and S as operators and an inner product space if the following are true:

A) $\langle Tx,Tx\rangle = \langle x,T^*Tx\rangle$ or $\langle x,TT^*x\rangle$

B) $\langle Tx,Tx\rangle = \langle T^*Tx,x\rangle$ or $\langle TT^*x,x\rangle$

Does anything still hold if we have a $y \neq x$?

C) $\langle Tx,Ty\rangle = \langle x,T^*Ty\rangle$ or $\langle x,TT^*y\rangle$

D) $\langle Tx,Ty\rangle = \langle T^*Tx,y\rangle$ or $\langle TT^*x,y\rangle$

Does anything still hold if we have a $S \neq T$?

E) $\langle Tx,Sx\rangle = \langle x,T^*Sx\rangle$ or $\langle x,ST^*x\rangle$

F) $\langle Tx,Sx\rangle = \langle TS^*x,x\rangle$ or $\langle S^*Tx,x\rangle$

G) $\langle Tx,Sy\rangle = \langle x,T^*Sy\rangle$ or $\langle x,ST^*y\rangle$

H) $\langle Tx,Sy\rangle = \langle TS^*x,y\rangle$ or $\langle S^*Tx,y\rangle$

I am sorry if this is a basic question, I just can't seem to find it in my book.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle for the inner product typesetting.

Comment: Oops sorry about that! I just saw this. But I see it was fixed already... Thank you for fixing it. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjoint $A^*$ of a linear map $A:U\to V$ satisfies (is defined by) the following equation, for all $u\in U, \, v\in V$
$$\langle v, Au\rangle=\langle A^*v, u\rangle$$
Using symmetry of the inner product (and taking complex conjugates in the complex case), this also means
$$\langle Au, v\rangle=\langle u, A^*v\rangle$$
Applying these properly answers each of your questions. E.g. take $A=T, \ u=x, \ v=Tx$ for A), B)